Issues with app-ads.txt Verification in Google AdMob
I’m encountering an issue with app-ads.txt verification in Google AdMob. I selected 'Verify App' in 'App Verification'. Despite following all the steps and confirming that the file is properly set up, I keep getting the error: "We couldn't verify", along with the following message from Google AdMob:
"Your details don't match the information in your AdMob account."
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
app-ads.txt File Accessibility:
The app-ads.txt file is hosted at:

http://theiafintech.com/app-ads.txt

theiafintech.com/app-ads.txt


Visiting either of these links returns the app-ads.txt content successfully.
I validated the file’s format using adstxt.guru, and it states that the file is formatted correctly.
Developer Website and App Store Integration:
The app is published on the Apple App Store, and clicking the 'App Support' link from the app listing successfully navigates to the company website: https://www.theiafintech.com/
Guide Reviewed:
I’ve carefully reviewed the AdMob instructions here. Everything appears to match the requirements, as the file is publicly accessible on both HTTP and HTTPS formats.
Issue:
Despite the above, Google AdMob is unable to verify the app-ads.txt file, and I continually get the error message "We couldn't verify."
Request:
Could someone help identify what might be going wrong? Are there additional steps or requirements (beyond those outlined in the guide) that I might be missing? I’d really appreciate any insights or suggestions.
Thank you for your help!
FYI:
Here’s what I get after selecting 'Verify App':


I went to your App page on the App Store, i think your "Marketing URL" is empty.
You'll need to re-publish with Marketing URL filled.
They use Marketing URL to reach the app-ads.txt
Step 1a https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?sjid=988135710817718778-NA#step1a

For Apple App Store: Add your developer website in the marketing URL
field of your store listing. Check if you can see the "Developer
Website" link displayed at the bottom of your iOS app page to confirm
that you successfully added the URL.


Thanks for the feedback.
We added developer website and still run into the same issue..

Did you wait enough time ?
I remember the first time i did the same mistake, after the developer website was added i had to wait 1-2 days before it got verified
